# Custom JButton not sizing properly?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, gridbaglayout

I am creating a matching game using Netbeans, but not the GUI editor (it sucks). So, basically, I created a new class, called Card, that extends the JButton class. Upon construction, the button's size is set to 100px by 100px and an icon is set. When I add the button to a JPanel in a GridBagLayout, it is not the intended size.

Here is some of my code:

JFRAME CLASS:

```
package matchinggame;

... imports ...

public class MatchingGameWindow extends JFrame {

    Card[] cards = new Card[16]; //16 game cards

    public MatchingGameWindow() {
         ...
         //Create new game panel (for the cards)
         JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
         //gamePanel.setSize(500,500); removed as it is not needed.
         ...
         this.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
         //Create 16 card objects
         cards = createCards();

         //Create new grid bag constraints
         GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

         //Add the cards to the game panel
         int i=0;
         for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
             gbc.gridy = y;
             for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                gbc.gridx = x;
                gamePanel.add(cards[i], gbc);
                i++;
             }
         }
    }

    public final Card[] createCards() {
        Card[] newCards = new Card[16];
        //New choices array
        ArrayList<Integer> choices = new ArrayList();
        int[] choiceValues = {0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7};
        //Add the initial choice values to the arraylist
        for (int i=0; i < choiceValues.length; i++) {
            choices.add(choiceValues[i]);
        }

        //Create 16 cards
        for (int i=0; i < 16; i++) {
            //Initial value of -1 for error checking
            int iconIndex = -1;
            //Loop until card is created
            while (iconIndex == -1) {    
                //Get a random number from 0 - 7
                Random r = new Random();
                int rInt = r.nextInt(8);
                //If the random number is one of the choices
                if (choices.contains(rInt)) {
                     //the icon # will be the random number
                     iconIndex = rInt;
                     //Get rid of that choice (it is used up)
                     choices.remove(new Integer(rInt));
                     //Create a new Card in the Card[]
                     newCards[i] = new Card(i,iconIndex);
                //If all the choices are gone
                } else if (choices.isEmpty()){
                    iconIndex = -1; //done creating this card (breaks out of loop)
                }
            }
        }
        //Return the created cards
        return newCards;
    }
}
```

CARD CLASS:

```
package matchinggame;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Card extends JButton {

    final static ImageIcon defaultIcon = new ImageIcon("cardback.jpg");
    ImageIcon secretIcon;
    boolean isRevealed = false;

    ...

    public Card(final int cardIndex, int secretIconIndex) { 
        //Size is 100px by 100px            
        setSize(100, 100);
        //Default icon is card back image
        setIcon(defaultIcon);
        //Get the secret icon behind the back of the card
        secretIcon = icons[secretIconIndex];    
    }
}
```

And using this code I get a result of this:
[image: This is the result.]

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT:
I overrided the getPreferredSize method like Hovercraft Full Of Eels said, and it worked!
I added this code in the Card class:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(100,100);
}
```

and got my desired result:
[image: Fixed!]

Now I must be doing something wrong with the icons, as they are not showing up as they should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `setSize(...)` in the class's constructor but rather override the class's `getPreferredSize()` method to return a Dimension(100, 100). And in fact you should have `setSize(...)` *no-where* in your program. Instead use decent layout managers, call `pack()` on the JFrame after adding all components and before setting it visible, and let the layout managers size the GUI appropriately.